# cascading parameters in tableau

Tags: cascadingdropdown, tableau-api

Did any one work with cascading parameters in tableau? It means when we select country parameter as Australia it should only show the states of Australia in the state parameter..
I have tried through data blending as few ppl suggested. but could not achieved it. do we have any options in tableau?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with parameters. You could use filters instead

Comment: I tried it using filters for the particular columns. But it shows bunch of states instead of showing for particular country states in the filter list

Comment: Watched a demo on Tableau 9.0 that demonstrated exactly what you need. When you filter Australia, the State filter will only show states in Australia.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hierarchy and use the hierarchy as a quick filter.

1. Drag **State** field onto **Country** field to create a hierarchy
2. Create a quick filter on **Country**
3. Create a quick filter on **State** or use it in your view

Answer (score 0):

Tableau does not support cascading parameters. 
However you can use context of dimensional filters for cascading filters